# Dialogflow - how to relate between product price and product name

Tags: dialogflow-es

Im quite new in using Dialogflow. At the moment Im trying to develop a simple chatbot that can entertain the user with basic infos on the products we offers. My problem is I couldnt managed to set a right respond when the user asking for the price for certain product. For example, if the user ask "What is the price for this bag ?" I couldnt find a way to relate the bag and its price using the Entities features or any other means. Hopefully somebody can help with this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: When the user says "this bag"? How do you know which bag the user is talking about?

Comment: Just assume there is only one type of bag in the whole line of products. Its just an example.

Answer (score 2):

The following is the way I would do it:

1. Create new entity `product`. Add a few examples, bag, bottle, boot, etc.
2. Create a new intent `getProductPrice` with training phrases like: how much does the bag cost?, What is the price of the bottle?, etc.
3. Enable [fulfilment](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-overview) for the intent.
4. Use the [inline fulfilment](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-inline-editor) or the [webhook](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-webhook) to parse the product parameter from the fulfilment request and return the response string which contains the price of the product.

Comment: Can I just create the data(json, etc) in the fulfilment or I have to create an API from external database   ?

Comment: Both the approaches would work but creating the data in the fulfilment every time would be inefficient.